# Validate email based on list selection - php

Tags: php

I have a list box with two values 'Student' and 'Business' I also have a input box for email and a submit button.  When a user selects 'Student' they should only be allow enter an email address with @mail.ITname.ie. When business is selected it should just check for a valid email.  I'm really new to php and finding it really hard to find tutorials to do what i'm look for. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']) == true && empty($_POST['email']) == false){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $allowed = array('mail.ITname.com');

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == true)
        {
            $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));

            if ( ! in_array($domain, $allowed))
            {
                // Not allowed
            }
        }
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="user type" size="2" >
      <option>Student</option>
      <option>Business</option>
    </select>
    <br />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing what I mentioned in my post

Comment: Looks like you're making fairly good progress. Is there a specific part that isn't working?

Comment: once `<option>` has a `name` you can check it with `$_POST['user_type']` !!`change user` type to `user_type`

Comment: @jszobody the code above is working fine for basic email validation. Its validating the email based on the selected list item that i'm not too sure how to approach

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<select>` name first off to something like this (no spaces):

```
<select name="user_type" size="2" >
```

Then you can just check `$_POST['user_type']` server side and handle the validation appropriately.

It'll probably end up looking something like this:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    if($_POST['user_type'] == 'Student') {
        // Validate the domain
        $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));
        if (in_array($domain, $allowed)) {
            // Email is valid.
        }
    } else {
        // User must be 'Business', so we're done. Email is valid.
    }
}

// Validation failed somewhere. Display an error? Redirect?
```